# Override OnClose()

Tags: c++, events, mfc

I got this class

```
class CWebBrowser2 : public CWnd
```

And i want to override OnClose What i have done so far is in the header file I added  void OnClose(); and in the .cpp file i added

```
void CWebBrowser2::OnClose ()
{
        int i=0;
        i++;
}
```

But the OnClose is never called.

Then I tried to to modify the header file to

```
afx_msg void OnClose();
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And added this to the .cpp file

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CWebBrowser2, CWnd)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CBrowserDlg)
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

But still OnClose is never called. I have tried to Change to OnClose to OnDestroy but that isnt called either.

any ideas on what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After adding the `ON_WM_CLOSE()` it should work.  In which way are you closing the window?

In your header file of your class do you have this line? `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()`

Answer (score 1):

Although my answer is three *years* late, I expect others may end up here (as I did) trying to resolve this problem. The OP did write the message handling correctly, but when you dynamically create an ActiveX control (as is usually done when using CWebBrowser2), you need to subclass the HWND that is associated with the control. You can read about this at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156051.

```
// This is how the control is normally created (i.e., dynamically):

/* CWebBrowser2 * */ pBrowser = new CWebBrowser2;
CWebBrowser2 * pBrowser = new CWebBrowser2;
ASSERT(pBrowser);

if (!pBrowser->Create(_T("windowname"), _T("classname"), WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0,0,0,0), this, ID_OF_BROWSER))
{
    TRACE( _T("An error occurred creating the Map tab"), true, false );
    delete pBrowser;
    pBrowser = NULL;
    return 0;
}

// Add these two lines so your control receives Windows messages:
HWND hWnd = pBrowser->Detach();
pBrowser->SubclassWindow(hWnd);
```